# An algorithm about sort

Tags: sorting

Suppose that you are given a sequence of n elements to sort. The input sequence
consists of n=k subsequences, each containing k elements.The elements in a given
subsequence are all smaller than the elements in the succeeding subsequence and
larger than the elements in the preceding subsequence.

So is there a O(nlogk) method to put a disordered array to an array described above?  thx!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO a008! Interesting question! Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: No... I just worked out a problem in Introduction to Algorithm. It's about sorting an array which is mentioned above,"Suppose that you are given a sequence of n elements to sort,....", and it can be sovled in O(nlogk).. So I wonder if there is a way to put a disorded array to an array like that in O(nlogk)

Comment: Great! Not a homework question then. I can see that you are talking about 8.1-4 and you are now wondering if one can do some nifty tricks by taking any unsorted array to that state and which we know from 8.1-4 can be solved in Ω(n log k).

Comment: I think it should say n/k not n=k in your question?

Comment: @AlexTelon Do you have the book? Does it explain this more? What is a "succeeding"/"preceding" subsequence? If n=k=2 and the whole sequence is [1,3,4,2], with the two subsequences [1,2] and [3,4], is subsequence [1,2] "preceding" the other because its first element comes first?

Comment: Yes I have it and it does not say much more. Do note that if n=k=2 then the whole sequence cannot be [1, 3, 4, 2] since that would be n = 4. 

The idea is basically that you have n/k buckets in a line. Every element in buckets to the right are larger than any element in the buckets to the left.

So [2, 1] is "preceding" [4,3] because all values in the right one are larger than the any value found in the left one. And here I showed them unsorted because the subsequences do not have to be internally sorted. (btw this is on page 194 in the 3rd edition)

Comment: @AlexTelon Sorry, I meant n=4, k=2. Ok, so the "preceding"/"succeeding" has nothing to do with the positions of their elements but only with the element values?

Comment: @HeapOverflow Yes that is my understanding. Each subsequence could just as well been a set in a mathematical sense where there is no order within the set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A different formulation of the question**

The question can be thought of like this. You have n balls of different sizes. You want to organize these into n/k buckets such that each bucket contains exactly k balls. Furthermore these buckets are placed in a line in which the left most bucket contains the k smallest balls. The 2nd bucket from the left contains the next k balls that would have been the smallest if we were to remove the leftmost bucket. The rightmost bucket contains the k largest balls.

But within each bucket you have no order. If you want the largest ball you know which bucket you must begin searching in, but you still need to search around in it.

I will be using the term bucket instead of subsequence since subsequence makes me think about ordering which is not important, what is important is belonging so bucket is easier for me.

**A problem with the proposed complexity of the imagined solution**

You are stating that k is the length (or size) of each bucket. It therefore naturally can be between 1 and n.

You then ask for if a O(n log k) solution exists that can organize the elements in this manner. There is a problem with your proposed complexity that is easy to see when we consider the two extremes k=1 and k=n.

k=n. Meaning we only have one large bucket. This is trivial since no action is needed. But your proposed complexity was O(n log k) = O(n log n) when k = n.

Let us consider k=1 too because it has a similar, but inverse, issue.

k=1. Each bucket contains 1 ball, and we need n buckets. This is the same as asking us to fully sort the whole sequence which will at best be O(n log n). But your proposed complexity was O(n log k) = O(n log 1) = O(n * 0) = 0. Remember log 1 = 0. It seems that your proposed complexity does not fit the problem at all.

We can pause here and say. No, you cannot do what you wish on O(n log k) because it does not make sense that the problem would become harder when you decrease the number of buckets. More importantly it cannot become easier as you increase the number of buckets.

If I were tasked to do this sorting manually I would say is trivial to sort into one bucket. Two is easy. Three would be harder than two. If you have n buckets then that is as hard as it can get!

**Answer for an altered complexity**
It is however interesting to consider what would happen if we were to fix your proposed complexity so that we instead ask the following. Is there a way to sort into these buckets in O(n log b) where b is the number of buckets (b = n / k)?

The extreme cases here seem to make sense.

b=1. One bucket. No sorting needed. O(n log b) = O(n log 1) = O(0). (technically this should still maybe be O(1))

b=n. n buckets. Full sort needed. O(n log b) = O(n log n).

So a solution seems possible. But this is outside the scope of the question now. I however suspect that [Selection Algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) and [quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) are the way to go.

Comment: Earlier you said "n/k buckets" (of k elements each). Here you're using k as the number of buckets instead of the bucket size. That seems wrong. Also, it's not clear what a "bucket" is.

Comment: You are correct. Every time I used k above I should have said n/k and I need to flip around a few other things too. Thanks, will make an update. I use bucket instead of subsequence since it for me conveyed the fact that the subsequences need not be sorted. Like in bucket sort we just throw the elements to the correct bucket but do not care to organize anything within a bucket.

Comment: @HeapOverflow I realized using k correctly as given by OP did not make sense and tried to explain that in my updated answer. I don't know if my musings make sense but I learned a lot while thinking about this.

Comment: You say *"these buckets are placed in a line in which the left most bucket contains the k smallest balls"*. It's not clear where that's from. It's not in the question. Like I said previously, you could for example have [1,3,4,2] with the subsequences [1,2] and [3,4]. This also makes the k=1 case trivial, as then *any* order of the whole sequence is already good (unless there are duplicates, in which case it's impossible). No sorting necessary in this case. Actually, if it's possible at all (duplicates determine that), it's *always* trivial, for any ...

Comment: ... order of the sequence. Just call the smallest k values the "first" subsequence, the next smallest k values the "second" subsequence, and so on. No rearranging required, ever. Thus the question doesn't really make any sense...

Comment: @HeapOverflow I believe that the what the author of the book means with subsequence is not the definition used in math. The question from the book states: "Suppose that you are given a sequence of n elements to sort. The input sequence consists of n/k subsequences, each containing k elements. The elements ina given subsequence are all smaller than the elements in the succeeding subsequence and larger than the lements in the preceding subsequence. Thus, all that is needed to sort the whole sequence of length is to sort the k elements in each of the n/k subsequences."

Comment: The last sentence gives important context that was missing for you. That sentence seems to indicate that the subsequences do come in order left to right.

{1 3 4 2 5} { 8 6 9 7 10 } { 15 14 11 12 13}

The order within each "sub-sequence" is such that if each part is sorted the full part is sorted. I can understand your confusion since you obviously were thinking about proper subsequences. You asked earlier for if more context was given and I should have added this part for you.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Yes, that last sentence indeed sounds like they don't just mean any subsequences but contiguous ones. They should've said that right away. I'm quite certain that if you look up their definition of "subsequence", they've used the standard definition. And given that you can then sort the whole by sorting the parts in O(n log k), it's pretty clear that *creating* this state can't be done in O(n log k) as well, as then you could sort a totally unordered sequence in 2*O(n log k) = O(n log k). But as you said, O(n log n/k) can work, since then the two parts ...

Comment: ... would be O(n log n/k) and O(n log k), which add up to O(n log n). And I agree that with a linear time selection algorithm it's indeed be possible.

Comment: Thanks! It's a wise choice to consider the extreme cases and as you say, it's imposible. And I agree that this problem may be sovled in O(nlogn/k)...maybe quicksort is a nice choice : )

Comment: @a008 I assume you typed the wrong thing just from habit, I almost did the same thing. But just in case, I was talking about quickSELECT, not quickSORT.

Comment: Ah! yes, quickselect. they both use “pivot” so I make a mistake, actually they are quite different, haha